# Verificar si ID existe en otra tabla mysql

Tags: mysql

Deseo saber como indentificar si existe el id de una Tabla A en una Tabla B.
tengo la siguiente estructura:

**Tabla A**
[image: Tabla A]

**Tabla B**
[image: Tabla B]

Dentro de la TABLA A existe el id el cual tambien puede o no existir en la TABLA B.

la idea es de pronto retornar un indicador / flag si un id existe o no en la tabla B.

La verdad no tengo idea como hacer alguna ayuda o link,, gracias !!

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. Sería bueno que pusieras un ejemplo de los resultados que esperas. Por ejemplo, ¿quieres que en una columna te aparezca el valor del id de la Tabla A y en otra columna un indicador de si ese id existe o no en la Tabla B?

Comment: En efecto busco un indicador si existe o no ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pondre la respuesta si a alguien le sirve de referencia:

**suponiendo las siguientes tablas:**

```
Table A
------------------
id | name |
 1 | beer |
 2 | wine |
------------------
table B
-----------------
id | id_table_a
1  | 1
```

**y mi resultado esperado quisiera algo asi:**

```
-------------------------------
id | name | id_table_a | flag |
 1 | beer | 1          | 1    |
 2 | wine | Null       | 0    |
-------------------------------
```

la respuesta seria la siguiente:

```
select a.*, b.id_table_a, case when b.id_table_a is null then 0 else 1 end as flag 
from tablea a
left join tableb b on a.id = b.id_table_a
```

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres hacer es hacer un query para validar si el id xx de la tabla A esta en la tabla B puedes hacer

```
SELECT id FROM A WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM B) WHERE id = xx
```

Answer (score 1):

Basado en la respuesta de Diego Ávila, en mi caso necesitaba enlistar los que no tuvieran el ID de la tabla A en la Tabla B y así lo logre:

```
SELECT Eventos.*, Control_Vehiculos.CV_Id_Evento
FROM Eventos 
LEFT JOIN Control_Vehiculos ON Eventos.id = Control_Vehiculos.CV_Id_Evento
WHERE status = 'Aceptada' AND CV_Id_Evento IS NULL
```

Eventos = **Tabla A**

Control_Vehiculos = **Tabla B**

Esto me sirvió para validar y descartar los que ya tuvieran un registro hecho.

Answer (score 0):

Si querés  flaguear los elementos de una tabla que se encuentran en la otra podes hacer esto.

```
Update tabla_a , tabla_b  set tabla_a.flag=1 where tabla_a.id=tabla_b.id
```

Esta consulta te va a poner un 1 en el campo flag  de la tabla a . Tenes que crear el campo flag o elegir el que quieras.
La otra a tomar en cuenta es que primero tabla de la comparación la que tiene mayor cantidad de registros y luego la mas chica.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo voy a probar !!